# How to produce avro format data onto topic in kstreams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry

```
KStream<String, String> left = builder.stream("source1");

left.toStream("soure2")
```

want to serialize before sending to source2

Answer (score 0):

```
GenericRecord genericRecord2 = new GenericData.Record(schema);
```

Get the schema using GenericRecord obj and then put key, value  in`

```
genericRecord2.put(k, v);
```

and once you are done with put operation, Write it to the topic using .to() method of the kstream api

```
.to("topic",Produced.with(stringSerde, genericAvroSerde));`
```

Make sure to register the avro schema in the schema-registry

Comment: you can always print the kstream values using
`kstreamRef.print();`